# WPF - Create buttons with up and down arrows using standard buttons

Tags: wpf, button

I want to create some up and down buttons using the standard button
background but with black arrows.

What is the best way to accomplish this with WPF??

Malcolm

Answer (score 180, accepted):

I find Marlett (a font built into Windows) handy for that sort of thing.

```
<Button FontFamily="Marlett" FontSize="20" Content="5"/>
<Button FontFamily="Marlett" FontSize="20" Content="6"/>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Wow. I know this isn't as "WPF-y" as drawing a triangular polygon by hand, but still ... didn't expect down-votes.

Comment: I reckon it's an OK way to go, what other interesting symbols are in the font?

Comment: Click Start|Run and type "charmap" - then you can switch to Marlett and have a look. I believe it's the font that Windows 95 originally used to render all its UI button glyphs.

Comment: +1 Fixed my problem. Much nicer than drawing a triangle each time. Very handy to know. Thanks!

Comment: In Silverlight "Webdings" would be the font to use for this.

Comment: This may as per Taran's answer now be an outdated font, at least it is available on all Windows versions from 7 and up.

Comment: @Dabblernl I ran this on a windows XP box and it worked fine also.

Comment: @Matt Hamilton , what would be there content for left and right arrows ?

Comment: Amazing!
Would be nice if you can expand the answer to include some basic icons, such as arrow up, arrow down, plus minus etc.

Comment: @shimmy Run charmap.exe, switch to the Marlett font, and copy/paste to your heart's content. There aren't a whole lot of symbols in there but they're useful.

Comment: @MattHamilton Yeah I just did it. Looks like the Marlett font is pretty limited. Anyway it's still good to know! Thanks for your quick response!

Comment: Coupling yourself to a font that you cannot guarantee will be present in future OS versions seems not a very good solution.

Answer (score 116):

No discussion on this subject would be complete without mentioning the geometry mini-language (or [Path Markup Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293.aspx)) for a more compact shape definition:-

```
  <Button>
    <Path Fill="Black" Data="M 0 6 L 12 6 L 6 0 Z"/>
  </Button>
  <Button>
    <Path Fill="Black" Data="M 0 0 L 6 6 L 12 0 Z"/>
  </Button>
```

The first describes a Move to 0,6 Line to 12,6 Line to 6,0 and then close the shape (Z).

There is also a curve syntax.

Comment: Left and right arrows, respectively: Data="M -2 6 L 4 12 L 4 0 Z" Data="M 2 12 L 9 6 L 2 0 Z"

Comment: @Tim These are not symmetrical :/

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :) finally know what these characters L,M,Z stand for!!

Answer (score 48):

The preferred way to do this now is using [Segoe UI Symbol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/windows/apps/jj841126.aspx). It replaces Marlett and provides many useful glyphs.
Up and down would be

```
<Button FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Content="&#xE1FD;"/>    
<Button FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Content="&#xE110;"/>
```

Which renders as:

[image: updown]

This font is pre-installed on all versions of Windows 7 and 8.

As of the release of Windows 10, the Segoe UI Symbol font is considered a legacy resource and should be replaced by Segoe MDL2 Assets in all new projects as [outlined here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font#about-segoe-mdl2-assets).

Comment: This font has been replaced by Segoe MDL2 Assets for Windows 10. The link provided for Segoe UI Symbol leads there now. Note that Segoe UI Symbol is not present on Windows 10 and that Segoe MDL2 Assets is not present on Windows 8.1.

Comment: This answer should be upvoted more for visibility since it's the go-to method nowadays.

Answer (score 7):

You can create a `Polygon` which represents your up and down triangles and then set them to be the content of the buttons:

```
<Button>
  <Polygon 
    Points="300,200 450,200 375,300 300,200"
    Stroke="Black">
    <Polygon.Fill>
      <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" />
    </Polygon.Fill>
  </Polygon>
</Button>
```

You can tweak these to draw different figured, but that's generally the XAML you would use for basic geometry.

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to have an arrow with base rectangle you can use this sample...

```
<Button >
   <Polygon   Stretch="Fill"  Fill="Black" Points="0,0 0,30 0,10 30,10 30,-10 45,10 30,30 30,20 0,20 0,0 30,0 30,10 0,10" />
</Button>
```