# Draw solid color triangle using XAML only

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, draw

Is it possible to draw a filled in triangle using XAML only (not a code behind solution)?

Triangle should be like on the image below to represent sort direction `Ascending/Descending` along with a sort button on a chart control:

[image]

**EDIT:** The solution, thanks to [SpeziFish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/444231/spezifish):

Ascending:

```
<Polygon Points="0,0 8,5, 0,10" Stroke="Black" Fill="Black" />
```

Descending:

```
<Polygon Points="8,0 0,5, 8,10" Stroke="Black" Fill="Black" />
```

Comment: Drawing a triangle with an rectangle? You could look into `Path` instead. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432384/wpf-create-buttons-with-up-and-down-arrows-using-standard-buttons/433818#433818) for a basic example.

Comment: @erikH : sorry, the main requirement is a XAML only

Answer (score 111, accepted):

```
<Polygon Points="0,0 80,50, 0,100" Stroke="Black" Fill="Black" />
```

See [API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.polygon.aspx) or [Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745818.aspx).

Comment: sorry, the main requirement is a XAML only so Polygon is fine. How to make it smaller 10 times?

Comment: Devide the numbers by ten. The numbers are easily the pixel coordinates (x,y) of the corners.

Comment: how do you position and rotate though? I mean I want to draw a triangle that will be position around a circle (outside that circle) based on binding. Any ideas?

Comment: for scaling you may add "Stretch=Fill", so it gets scaled to fit the parent container, e.g. Button.Content..)
Ok, just spotted it in the answer of @LongZheng :)

Answer (score 38):

I want to add these to their collection:

[image]

```
    <Polygon Points="5,0 10,10, 0,10" Stroke="Black" Fill="Black" />
```

[image]

```
    <Polygon Points="0,0 5,10, 10,0" Stroke="Black" Fill="Black" />
```

Answer (score 26):

Using paths

```
<Path Width="33" Height="37" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" Fill="Black" Data="F1 M 319.344,237.333L 287.328,218.849L 287.328,255.818L 319.344,237.333 Z "/>
<Path Width="33" Height="37" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" Fill="Black" Data="F1 M 287.328,237.333L 319.344,255.818L 319.344,218.849L 287.328,237.333 Z "/>
```

Comment: how do you position and rotate though? I mean I want to draw a triangle that will be position around a circle (outside that circle) based on binding. Any ideas?

Comment: LayoutTransform could help you out. Maybe the best shot is, to create a Usercontrol with a 'Direction' Dependency Property so you could place it as often you need w/o rewriting the xaml