# Any way to style a line such that the line cap is 'halved'? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, line

I wish to style my line such that the end line cap is 'halved', as you can see here in my crudely drawn Paint sketch:

[image]

I'm thinking about a hacky solution where I create a user control with two lines, and one of them splits the line in half in some way by making it white and the other black, but I don't know how feasible or good that would look. Does anyone have any ideas or thoughts? Cheers.

Comment: Why dont a shorter line + a polygon following it? [Draw solid color triangle using XAML only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874822/draw-solid-color-triangle-using-xaml-only)

Comment: BTW, whatever your final solution is, consider making it a user control if possible because of reusability.

Comment: So essentially a line with a triangle on the end? Sounds like it might be what I'm looking for, cheers! @bradbury9