# SymbolIcon is not supported in a WPF Project

Tags: wpf, glyphicons

I am trying to use `SymbolIcon` (as defined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.symbolicon.aspx) in my WPF-XAML code.
But XAML won't compile stating that "SymbolIcon is not supported in a WPF Project".

Could anyone tell me if I am missing any additional assembly to use SymbolIcon. I do have "Segoe UI Symbol" font on my box.

Thanks,
RDV

Comment: your application is a Desktop WPF application? (I see from the link and looks like just windows phone applications are supported).

Comment: WPF is **only** for desktop applications.  Unless you count XBAP, but nobody in their right mind uses that.

Comment: Thanks King King. Yes, I am using WPF desktop App. Microsoft website doesn't clearly state that this is only for Phone. RDV

Answer (score 6):

`SymbolIcon` is a UWP control, and is not supported in WPF.

What you can do is:

- Use a [XAML Island](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/xaml-islands) to host the `SymbolIcon` control in your WPF app (Windows 10 1903+).
- Use the WPF Toolkit [`IconButton`](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/IconButton).
- Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/432394/75500) suggestion:
  `<Button FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Content="&#xE110;"/>`
  Which renders like this:
  [image]